# Return maximum element

Tags: java

I wrote this program which can count the number of pizzas ordered.

I can't find how to return the maximum element of my list (the pizza with maximum orders).

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
return order.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(norder::pizza)).get();
```

```
public class PizzaCount {
 
    private ArrayList<String> order;
    private String[] menu;
 
    public PizzaCount(String[] pizzas) {
        this.menu = pizzas;
        this.order = new ArrayList<>();
    }
 
    public int norder(String pizza) {
        int number=0;
        for(String pizzaOrdered : this.order){
            if(pizza(pizzaOrdered)){
                number++;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
     
    public String pizzamax() {
        /*stuck here*/
    }
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String [] menu = {"romana", "funghi"};
            PizzaCount n = new PizzaCount(menu);
            n.add("romana");
            n.add("romana");
            n.add("funghi");
            System.out.println("number of romana: "+ n.norder("romana"));
            System.out.println("number of funghi: "+ n.norder("funghi"));
            System.out.println("the pizza with the maximum order is: "+ n.pizzamax());
        }
}
```

Comment: [`Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,java.util.Comparator))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can try this

```
order.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(this::norder)).get();
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help, I understand where I was wrong.

Comment: It takes O(n²).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to count the number of orders for each pizza(you can create a map with order amount as value and pizza name as a key) and after this, you can find the maximum by that number. If you want to do it with stream API it will look like this.

```
order.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .get();
```